Compute inverse of $I + CBC^\top$ where $B$ is zero-padded and $C$ is Toeplitz.
I want to compute inverses for matrices of the following form:
$$
Q = I + C \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{0}_{n\times n} & & (0) \\
    & A & \\
    (0) & & \mathbf{0}_{m\times m}
\end{bmatrix} C^\top
$$
where

$\text{dim}(Q) >> \dim(A)$,
$A$ is symmetric and positive definite,
$C$ is rectangular Toeplitz,
$\mathbf{0}_{p \times q}$ denotes a matrix of zeroes of dimension $p \times q$.
The $(0)$ indicates that the rest of the matrix $B$ is filled with zeroes.
$\dim(A) + m + n = \dim(Q)$, and
$I$ is the identity matrix.

I'm hoping for an expression(s) for $Q^{-1}$ that'll make its computation more efficient since $\dim(Q)$ is very large.

I know that the Woodbury identity is probably helpful here, but I can't figure how to incorporate the other aforementioned properties to fully simplify the expression.
Would low-rank perturbation or related methods apply here? I have very little idea of their working but they seem related.
Note that $B$ may also be represented as $D_n A D_n^\top$ where $D_n$ is a non-cyclic lower shift matrix that shifts elements of a column vector down by $n$ places upon left-multiplication (its dimensions are $\dim(Q)\times \dim(A)$).

I made some progress so I'm going to try to answer my own question.
First, let's column-partition $C$ so as to carry out block matrix multiplication:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Q &= I + \begin{bmatrix}
    E_1 & E & E_2
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{0}_{n \times n} & & (0) \\
    & A & \\
    (0) & & \mathbf{0}_{m \times m} 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    E_1^\top \\
    E^\top \\
    E_2^\top
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= I + E A E^\top .
\end{aligned}
$$
Here $E_1$, $E_2$ and $E$ have $n$, $m$, and $\dim(A)$ columns respectively.
Then, applying the Woodbury identity,
$$
\begin{aligned}
Q^{-1} &= (I + E A E^\top)^{-1} \\
&= I - E (A^{-1} + E^\top E)^{-1} E^\top.
\end{aligned}
$$
This is great since both matrix inverse computations involve small ($\dim(A)$) matrices.
However, I still haven't used the Toeplitz property of $E$ (which it inherits from $C$). There may also be shortcuts to calculate $E^\top E$ or $E M E ^\top$ which I'm not aware of. Maybe another answerer can address that.
